# how to check image value with tab host

Tags: android-tabhost

Ok so i will try to explain what im trying to do as clearly as possible with examples.

i have a tabhost with 5 tabs (engine,body,photo,spec,colors).
the upper portion of the xml layout(car.xml) has an imageView1.
and the and the lower portion of the layout car.xml holds the tabs. each tab calls an intent.
such as  "" car.this.coupe_specs = new Intent(this, coupe_tab.class); ""

and coupe_tab.xml layout has 1 textView.

now what i am trying to do is change the text in the textView field in coupe_tab.xml
after checking the id: of the imageView1  on the car.xml.

so basicly i want to from car.java  check the value of a ImageView in car.java and if true change the text in the TextView in coupe_tab.java the problem i seem to be having is doing all this inside a onItemSelected function.

non functional example just to help you under stand my wants
example:

```
 import com.myexample._coupe_tab;

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> example int view) {

 if ("car.png").equals imageView1 {     
 textView1 = "example text 1";
        }

else if ("car2.png).equals imageView1 {
textView1 = "example text 2"; 
        }

else {  
     // do something else
   }
```